# How to retrieve value from optional parser in Parsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell, option-type, parsec

Sorry if it's a novice question - I want to parse something defined by

```
Exp ::= Mandatory_Part Optional_Part0 Optional_Part1
```

I *thought* I could do this:

```
proc::Parser String

proc = do {

    ;str<-parserMandatoryPart

    ;str0<-optional(parserOptionalPart0)  --(1)

    ;str1<-optional(parserOptionalPart1)  --(2)

    ;return str++str0++str1

}
```

I want to get str0/str1 if optional parts are present, otherwise, str0/str1 would be "".
But (1) and (2) won't work since optional() doesn't allow extracting result from its parameters, in this case, parserOptionalPart0/parserOptionalPart1.

Now What would be the *proper* way to do it?

Many thanks!

Billy R

Answer (score 6):

The function you're looking for is `optionMaybe`. It returns `Nothing` if the parser failed, and returns the content in `Just` if it consumed input.

Answer (score 5):

From [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html):

> `option x p` tries to apply parser `p`. If `p` fails without consuming input, it returns the value `x`, otherwise the value returned by `p`.

So you could do:

```
proc :: Parser String
proc = do
  str  <- parserMandatoryPart
  str0 <- option "" parserOptionalPart0
  str1 <- option "" parserOptionalPart1
  return (str++str0++str1)
```

Watch out for the "without consuming input" part.  You may need to wrap either or both optional parsers with `try`.

I've also adjusted your code style to be more standard, and fixed an error on the last line.  `return` isn't a keyword; it's an ordinary function.  So `return a ++ b` is `(return a) ++ b`, i.e. almost never what you want.

Comment: Keegan, thanks for the answer and correcting my code. It worked mostly as I wanted - there's some issues with cases not described in original post. I am new to both Haskell & Parsec, I'll just read & try more. Thanks.