# Parse a list whose separator may also occur at the end

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to parse some text, but I can't understand how to parse a list of symbols separated by some separator, which may or may not occur also at the end of the list.

Example (numbers separated by spaces):

```
set A = 1 2 3 4 5;
set B =6 7 8 9;
set C = 10 11 12 ;
```

If I use `sepBy`, after the last space I got an error because it expects another digit, even if I try to read also `many whitespace` after the list. If I use `endBy`, I got an error when the space is missing.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let input = "set A = 1 2 3 4 5;\n" ++
              "set B =6 7 8 9;\n" ++
              "set C = 10 11 12 ;\n"
  case parse parseInput "(unknown)" input of
    Left msg ->
      print msg
    Right rss ->
      mapM_ (\(n, vs) -> putStrLn (n ++ " = " ++ show vs)) rss

whitespace :: GenParser Char st Char
whitespace = oneOf " \t"

parseInput :: GenParser Char st [(String, [Int])]
parseInput = parseRow `endBy` newline

parseRow :: GenParser Char st (String, [Int])
parseRow = do
  string "set"
  many1 whitespace
  name <- many1 alphaNum
  many whitespace
  string "="
  many whitespace
  values <- many1 digit `sepBy` many1 whitespace
  many whitespace
  string ";"
  return (name, map read values)
```

Comment: This previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921559/haskell-parsec-optional-question might be of some use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The combinator I think you want is [`sepEndBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v%3asepEndBy). Using it gives you

```
-- I'm using the type synonym
-- type Parser = GenParser Char ()
-- from Text.ParseCombinator.Parsec.Prim
parseRow :: Parser (String, [Int])
parseRow = do
  string "set" >> many1 whitespace
  name <- many1 alphaNum
  spaces >> char '=' >> spaces
  values <- many1 digit `sepEndBy` many1 whitespace
  char ';'
  return (name, map read values)
  where spaces = many whitespace
```